# Showing items in the same page after selecting from a dropdown control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with an `Index` action which returns a `ViewModel` and a `GetCategories` action which should return a partial view.

So here is my `CategoryController.cs` file:

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CategoryViewModel ob = new CategoryViewModel();
            ob.LoadLanguages();
            return View(ob);
        }



        public ActionResult GetCategories(int langID)
        {
            CategoryViewModel ol = new CategoryViewModel();
            ol.LoadCategoriesByLanguage(langID);
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                           return PartialView("GetCategories",ol);
```

In my `Index.cshtml` view I create a dropdown list and, when the user selects an element, it makes an Ajax request to the `getCategories` action and on success I should load the `GetCategories` partial view. The problem is that it redirects me to a new page and I can no longer see my dropdown.

Here is my `Index.cshtml` file:

```
@model Onion.Web.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddlLanguages").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCategories")' + '?langId=' + this.value,
                data: {},
                success: callbackFuntion('@Url.Action("GetCategories")' + '?langId=' + this.value),
                error: function () { alert('Error'); }
            });
        });

    });

    function callbackFuntion(url){

        window.location = url;
    }
</script>
@Html.DropDownList("Languages", new SelectList(Model.lstLanguages, "LanguageID", "Name"), "SELCT  LANGUAGE----->",new { id = "ddlLanguages" })

            }
```

And here is my `Category.cshtml` file:

```
@model Onion.Web.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Title</td>

    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.lstCategoryLanguages)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Title</td>
            <td>@item.ShortDescription</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>


I can't beleve how easy it is in web forms and here i'm struggling for hours. Is there a better way to do all this. Thank you in advance
```

Comment: The problem you had is redirection to a new action on success. The advantage of ajax is to use the result and write it directly to your html controls using jQuery. ramiramilu showed how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal because you execute a redirection in your success callback.

You can use load function of jQuery to load your partial view in a div of your dom.

```
<div id="categoriesPlace"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlLanguages").change(function () {
        $("#categoriesPlace").load('@Url.Action("GetCategories")' + '?langId=' + this.value, function( response, status, xhr ) {
            if ( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                alert( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I slightly modified your Models and made it working prototype, from here you can get the concept and apply it to your models -

Models -

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public List<string> DDLItems { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryNewViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller -

```
public class MyPartialController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CategoryViewModel ob = new CategoryViewModel();
        ob.DDLItems = new List<string>();
        ob.DDLItems.Add("1");
        ob.DDLItems.Add("2");
        ob.DDLItems.Add("3");
        return View(ob);
    }

    public ActionResult GetCategories(int langID)
    {
        CategoryNewViewModel ol = new CategoryNewViewModel();

        if (langID == 1)
            ol.Name = "One";
        else if (langID == 2)
            ol.Name = "two";
        else
            ol.Name = "three";

        return PartialView("GetCategories", ol);
    }
}
```

Index View -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.CategoryViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DDLCategories").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCategories")',
                data: {langID : $('#DDLCategories').val()},
                success: function (result) { $('#container').html(result); },
                error: function () { alert('Error'); }
            });
        });

    });
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.DropDownList("DDLCategories", new SelectList(Model.DDLItems), "--Choose any Item--")

<div id="container"> </div>
```

GetCategories Partial View -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.CategoryNewViewModel

@Model.Name
```

When you select a item in Dropdownlist, then the corresponding partialview will be loaded in the div.

Output -

[image]